# New Activity from static method, Android Java

Tags: java, android, methods, android-activity, static

I'm making a question-type of game, where every different type of question has a different layout, and therefore also is a different Activity.

My main Activity, upon hitting the "play"- button should randomize a question with the corresponding Activity to start with.

Once a question is answered, this should be repeated. And to do so, I wanted to have a STATIC method that randomizes and starts the corresponding Activity, but I can't make it work.

This is when you initiate the game. It randomizes the first question. type ==3 is a type of a question(there are many different)

```
        if(Var.qList.get(Var.rndindex).getType()==3)

            startActivity(new Intent(this, PlayWordMeaning.class));
        }
```

And this works fine, but I have a Var.Class which holds all static stuff, and I'd like to have a method there **that picks the next question** so that I can call it from other question activities once a person have answered correctly. I tried to make a static method there with the same code, but it just didnt work, even if I sent the context.

Help me out guys please :)

Comment: Ur question is not clear, Not understandable..

Comment: Put simply: I want to have different views of my app: some with 2 buttons, some with 1 for example and I want to have a static method that randomizes a view for me.

Comment: you can do it by adding deleting views from screen and lots of other ways. If you can add an example in your question what you exactly looking for., One can answer

Comment: you should add a Context to your function parameters for this

Comment: In my MainActivity(main menu) I want the "play" button to call on a method that randomizes a new question(a new view!). After correctly answering each question, I want this method to be called again and again.... That's why I want it to be static, cause it's gonna have a lot of if-statements.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesn't help. Would it be okay to ask you guys for an example on this ?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First i would recommend you have a `plain Java class` that has a `randomize function`, be it static or not.... It **return a number randomly according to the total questions left .** (**Hint**: the question once asked will be removed from the list)

**2.** Use a Map to link the question number to the name of the Activity.

`HashMap< Integer,String >` **// where Integer will be the Ques, and String will be the Activity Name**

Comment: I do have a plain java class, that happens to have a randomize function, and it does exactly what you say. The range of it is from 0 to arraylist.lenght(). I also have a "garbage" list, where all the answered questions go.

I just dont really know how to start the activity using a generic solutio instead of copy-pasting a huge list of if-statements. Imagine that I want to have an external function taking care of the activity-changing. How do I pass on arguments and stuff? Once I get this done, the problem is solved :)

Comment: So you want to use delegation, as you mention external function taking care of ur work... if its passing of an Collection with Generics its like this... `public void go(ArrayList<? extends YourType> arr)`  <? extends YourType> means this method go() will accept any type which extends YourType

Comment: Could someone help me out with a code snippet about this? I am trained in the ways of programming but lack experience.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it correctly you could simply create an array of class Name and then generate a random number to pick up the class like that:

```
    Class[] actArr = new Class[2];

    actArr[0] = Activity2.class;
    actArr[1] = Activity3.class;

    Random rn = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int val = rn.nextInt(2);

    Intent in = new Intent(this, actArr[val]);
    startActivity(in);
```

It works!. Remember to put these activity classes in your AndroidManifest.xml file.